# Implementation details behind Mixpanel's opt-out page

Tags: javascript, cookies, tracking, mixpanel

What are the implementation details behind Mixpanel's opt-out page?

#### Background

Mixpanel has an opt-out page at https://mixpanel.com/optout/. Once you submit "Yes, I would like to opt out.", you supposedly won't be tracked on any site that leverages Mixpanel.

On the opt-out page, an "mp_optout" cookie gets set to "1".

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (mp.cookie.exists('mp_optout')) {
            $('#optout').prop('checked', true);
        }

        $('#save_button').click(function() {
            $('#saved_text').show();
            if ($('#optout').prop('checked')) {
                mp.cookie.set('mp_optout', 1, 9999, true);
            } else {
                mp.cookie.remove('mp_optout', true);
            }
        });
    });
```

How does this setting eventually communicate with their javascript file, https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min.js, to bypass tracking?

Answer (score 2):

Even after opting out Mixpanel still makes the tracking requests to the server. You can see the mp_optout cookie that is sent with these requests:

[image: Mixpanel network requests in Chrome developer tools]

You can look at the unminified JavaScript file by removing the ".min" from the URL: https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.3.js

If you search for "optout" you'll find this code:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", url, true);
// send the mp_optout cookie
// withCredentials cannot be modified until after calling .open on Android and Mobile Safari
req.withCredentials = true;
```

Since they explicitly want to make sure that the mp_output cookie is sent they probably use it on the backend to ignore the request and not store any data.

Comment: Wether they store or use the data or not, the tracking request is still sent, and thus they'll still be able to _receive_ it. Therefore their implementation is ineffective. Your opt-out intention is clearly disobeyed. When one opts out it must mean that no data is even sent, not that it's discarded or just not aggegated. If your browser sends a do-not-track header, the sending code shouldn't even be rendered, and no specific opt-out cookie should even be needed at _any_ tracking or analytics site in the first place. It's highly unethical to assume you're "in" to begin with *and* ignore DNT.

Comment: From their [privacy policy](https://mixpanel.com/legal/privacy-policy/): `Do Not Track Signals. Some web browsers may transmit “do not track” signals to the websites and other online services with which your web browser communications. There is no standard that governs what, if anything, websites should do if they receive these signals. Mixpanel currently does not respond to “Do Not Track” browser signals or similar mechanisms.` Every moron knows what "do not track" means, no "governing" standard needed. They are keen enough to blatantly admit they ignore ppls explicit wish regarding privacy.